# Is it possible to get the currently logged in admin's IP?

Tags: users, ip

Given a wordpress (3.4.x) install that only has 1 admin, how would I grab, from within a plugin, the IP of the currently logged in admin, if there is an admin logged in?

In other words: I need to obtain the IP of the  admin, IF there is admin is logged in, and use this IP for other purposes. The request will not necessarily come in from the person logged in as admin. If there is no admin logged in, the function should return empty, as I only need the IP of the admin WHILE he/she is logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is not directly available, you'll have to track the logins inside the database(probably as a transient) & check if that transient is available.

```
function check_for_admin() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if(in_array('administrator', $user->roles))
        set_transient('admin_ip', get_ip(), 60*10);
}
add_action('init', 'check_for_admin');
```

After that you can use `get_transient('admin_ip')` & check if it's available

For retrieving the IP, you may use toscho's code.

EDIT:

The `60*10` in the code means if no admin has been active for last 10 minutes, consider them all offline & cleanup the database.

It's also possible to delete the transient when user manually logs out, you need to hook into the `'clear_auth_cookie'` action to clean up the database.

```
function clear_the_transient() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if(in_array('administrator', $user->roles))
        delete_transient('admin_ip')
}
add_action('clear_auth_cookie', 'clear_the_transient');
```

This code will work in your case when there is only 1 administrator. But this code has a major problem, it deletes the IP from the database even if there are 2 administrators online & only one of them logged out. To overcome that situation, you will have to store the user id as well as their corresponding last activity time in the database.

Comment: Maybe I need to clarify that I need to obtain the IP of the  admin, IF there is admin is logged in, and use this IP for other purposes. The request will not necessarily come in from the person logged in as admin. If there is no admin logged in, the function should return empty, as I only need the IP of the admin WHILE he/she is logged in. Thanks

Comment: that's exactly what the `if(in_array('administrator', $user->roles))` will do. If user's role is 'administrator', only then the next statement is executed

Comment: Where is get_transient() defined?

Comment: `get_transient('admin_ip')` will return the admin ip if it's there in the database. Use it anywhere you want to retrieve the ip

Comment: That almost works, but even after the admin logs off `get_transient('admin_ip')` still returns the IP the admin last used.

Comment: please see the edit in the answer above

Comment: thanks @Mridul, it will work as I only have one admin. If come across a situation where I have two or more admins I will set the timeout to 60*3 and it will work well enough.

Comment: @Gaia "If come across a situation where I have two or more admins" ... than you add the user id (or the login name or something else from $user) to the transient: `set_transient('admin_ip_' . $user->ID, get_ip(), 60*10);`. Same with `delete_transient()`

Comment: @Ralf912 How to retieve(transients are not autoloaded) it? loop through every admin to check if their transient is set up? or a custom query to use mysql wildcards? It's easier as well as more efficient to store it as an array

Comment: @MridulAggarwal This depends on the number of data. If there are only  a few (two or three) admins, I would fetch all IDs of admins ( `$admins = get_users( array( 'role' => 'administrator' ) );`) and loop through the transients. On a comparable situation, but with thousands of users, I would use a custom query or store an array instead an extra transient for each user.

Comment: I disagree. Transient means only one database query. Looping through the transients means 1 query for every admin. If there are 3 admin then 3 queries i.e. should never be done. Custom query with wildcards overcome this issue(only 1 query) but is not preferred by a majority of developers. If you have thousands of users, transients become pointless, the time taken for transferring that much data & then serialize/unserilize gets too much to neglect. For this i suggest either user_meta or a new table

Answer (score 1):

Like any other IP, they are not different for admins …

```
function get_ip() 
{
    $ip      = '';
    $sources = array (
        'REMOTE_ADDR',
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',
        'HTTP_CLIENT_IP',
    );

    foreach ( $sources as $source ) {
        if ( isset ( $_SERVER[ $source ] ) )  {
            $ip = $_SERVER[ $source ];
        } elseif ( getenv( $source ) ) {
            $ip = getenv( $source );
        }
    }

    return $ip;
}
```

Make sure to [validate the value](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php).

Comment: I know how to get an IP, but I want the currently logged in ADMIN's IP.